# Facebook Approved Permission not in Approved Items

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I just got approved of `user_link` permission in facebook (From App Review) but I am not seeing it in my `Approved Items`. 
It says in the docs that `No Additional Requirements` for `user_link` is needed so I assumed that even without `Business/Individual Verification`, I can already use the permission in my app. 
Is that not how it works?

EDIT: (added screenshots)

[My Permissions and Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4fC5.png)

[Permissions and Features tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xlAy.png)

Comment: It should show under Approved Items, if it was successfully reviewed. Does it still show up when you go to the “Permissions and Features” tab?

Comment: @misorude Yes, it does show up in the Permissions and Features tab. I edited my post with a screenshots. Thank you

Comment: Can you ask normal users (without a role in the app) for the permission? If so, I wouldn’t worry about it. If not, file a bug report - occasionally the system appears to be a little glitchy, and the review result doesn’t “take”. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this permission after getting the Business Verification.